# Updating map values in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Newb question here:
how can I have the value stored in Maptest[2] update along with the variable?
I thought you could do it with pointers, but this doesn't work:

```
map<int, int*> MapTest; //create a map

    int x = 7; 

   //this part gives an error: 
   //"Indirection requires pointer operand ("int" invalid)"
    MapTest[2] = *x; 


    cout << MapTest[2]<<endl; //should print out 7...

    x = 10;

    cout <<MapTest[2]<<endl; //should print out 10...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sidenote: The `&` takes the address, the `*` is a dereference operator and derefs a pointer.

Comment: Since you want the pointer to x you should do something like this instead: `MapTest[2] = &x;`

Comment: code is wrong in a couple of aspects. Should be `MapTest[2] = &x; ` and use `*MapTest[2]` to access value. Are you familiar with pointer at all?

Comment: You may also consider `std::map<int, int& >`, so you don't have to dereference all the time. (a map can hold an `int&` right?  Since it's node based?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the *address of* `x`. Your current code is attempting to dereference an integer.

```
MapTest[2] = &x;
```

You then need to dereference what `MapTest[2]` returns.

```
cout << *MapTest[2]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
MapTest[2] = &x;
```

You want the address of x to store in the `int*`.  Not the dereference of x, which would be what ever is at the memory location 0x7, which is not going to be valid.

Comment: Also what Peter Alexander said about printing stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems here:

```
int x = 7;
*x; // dereferences a pointer and x is not a pointer.
m[2] = x; // tries to assign an int value to a pointer-to-int value
// right
m[2] = &x; // & returns the address of a value
```

Now you have a new problem. `x` has automatic lifetime, it will be
destroyed at the end of its surrounding scope. You need to allocate it
from the free store (a.k.a. the heap).

```
int* x = new int(7);
m[2] = x; // works assigns pointer-to-int value to a pointer-to-int value
```

Now you have to remember to `delete` every element in the `map` before
it goes out of scope or you will leak memory.

It is smarter to store values in a `map`, or if you really need to
store pointers to store a suitable smart pointer (`shared_ptr` or
`unique_ptr`).

For the printing:

```
m[2]; // returns pointer value
*m[2]; // dereferences said pointer value and gives you the value that is being pointed to
```